# Normal Form (Logic and sets)

Tags: logic

Using distribution laws the following

G <=> (A ^B^(¬C)) ˇ ((¬A)^B^C) ˇ ((¬A)^(¬B)^C) ˇ ((¬A)^(¬B)^(¬C))

"can be written" as

G <=> (A ^B^(¬C)) ˇ ((¬A)^B^C) ˇ ((¬A)^(¬B)) ˇ (Cˇ(¬C))

and (Cˇ(¬C)) is always true, we can write

G <=> (A ^B^(¬C)) ˇ ((¬A)^B^C) ˇ ((¬A)^(¬B))

which I understand, but the second row is what I can't understand.

It's taken from my professors Analysis script. 
Can somebody break it down?

Comment: Mathjax tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. Here, you're after `\iff`, `\neg`, `\land`, `\lor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manipulation of the first line into the second only concerns the last two terms, let's say $S$.

$$S=(\neg A\land\neg B\land C)\lor(\neg A\land\neg B\land\neg C)$$

Perhaps it'll be clearer to see how the next line is gotten if you let $D=\neg A\land\neg B$, and hence

$$S=(D\land C)\lor(D\land\neg C)$$

$$=D\land (C\lor\neg C)$$

$$=(\neg A\land\neg B)\land (C\lor\neg C)$$

Comment: I understand now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> Using distribution laws the following
>
> $G \iff (A \land B\land \lnot C) \lor (\lnot A\land B\land C) \lor (\lnot A\land \lnot B\land C) \lor (\lnot A\land \lnot B\land\lnot C)$
>
> "can be written" as
>
> $G \iff (A \land B\land \lnot C) \lor (\lnot A\land B\land C) \lor (\lnot A\land \lnot B) \lor (C\lor \lnot C)$

$\require{enclose}G \iff (A \land B\land \lnot C) \lor (\lnot A\land B\land C) \lor ((\lnot A\land \lnot B){\enclose{circle}[color:red]{\bbox[0.25ex, color:black]\land}} (C\lor \lnot C))$

> and $C\lor ¬C$ is always true, we can write
>
> $G \iff (A \land B\land \lnot C) \lor (\lnot A\land B\land C) \lor (\lnot A\land\lnot B)$
>
> which I understand, but the second row is what I can't understand.

That's *possibly* because you miscopied.